# How to persist/flush doctrine2 entities with OneToMany // ManyToOne relations?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, many-to-many, associations, persist

I am trying to persist/flush my doctrine2 entities, but I am gettig an error every time:

> Entity of type Test\Main\MainBundle\Entity\ProductVariantAssociation has identity
>       through a foreign entity Test\Main\MainBundle\Entity\Product, however this entity has 
>       no ientity itself. You have to call EntityManager#persist() on the related entity and make 
>       sure it an identifier was generated before trying to persist 
>       'Test\Main\MainBundle\Entity\ProductVariantAssociation'. In case of Post Insert ID 
>       Generation (such as MySQL Auto-Increment or PostgreSQL SERIAL) this means you have to call 
>       EntityManager#flush() between both persist operations.

I posted my ArticleController at pastebin:
http://pastebin.com/iN0BpGFc

Does anybody know, how to solve that problem?

Comment: Why didn't you try what is advised in the error (calling `flush()` between `persist()` calls)?

Comment: I hoped that it isn´t nesessary to flush two or more times and that there is a general problem...

Comment: a general solution, you mean. Maybe you should try using cascade : http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations